# Name node crash in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, bigdata

If a name node crashes,do we have to stop all our data processing and then manually go and get it up working(in case we dont have a secondary name node),or if we're using Cloudera latest ver.and if it crashes then it automatically names a secondary name node,does the data processing stop at any time during this crash.?(here we already have a secondary name node

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, it seems that namenode HA(High availability) is the setup you are after:

> The HDFS High Availability feature addresses the above problems by providing the option of running two redundant NameNodes in the same cluster in an Active/Passive configuration with a hot standby. This allows a fast failover to a new NameNode in the case that a machine crashes, or a graceful administrator-initiated failover for the purpose of planned maintenance.

See more details at Hadoop doc: [HDFS High Availability Using the Quorum Journal Manager](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSHighAvailabilityWithQJM.html)